# Declare Maven dependency as test runtime only

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

What is the best way to declare a Maven dependency as only being used for the test runtime (but not test compilation) class path?

Specifically, I want `slf4j-api` (a logging facade) as a typical, compile-scope dependency, but I want `slf4j-simple` (the barebones implementation suitable for unit tests) only on the test runtime class path (it's not needed for test compilation). I've been doing this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, the downside of this is that `dependency:analyze` reports `slf4j-simple` as unused, presumably because it's not needed for compilation:

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.7:test
```

I can't use a `runtime` dependency because I don't want that dependency transitively inherited (e.g. so downstream dependencies can use log4j, etc. instead). I tried `runtime` with `optional=true`, but that results in the same warning.

(Note that I could also set `ignoreNonCompile` for the dependency plugin, but that seems like a very blunt instrument that would hide other potential problems.)

Comment: what is this is required at runtime for main source ? won't it still complain for `runtime` scoped dependency ?

Comment: In general transitive dependencies need not be declared. For an optional dependency (typically like logging which can use different frameworks) your procedure is right. Maybe you can add a scope test too.

Comment: It does also complain (wrongly, IMHO) for a `runtime` dependency, so it seems like scope alone is not the answer here. What I really want is a scope that is the intersection of `test` and `runtime` (as far as the class path) and for the dependency plugin to act less dumb about "unused" `runtime` dependencies.

Comment: Another use case I’m coming across right now is when you want to avoid having JUnit 4 in your test classpath when compiling the tests, but you still need it to run the tests, e.g. when using Testcontainers’ `RabbitMQContainer` or `ElasticsearchContainer` (which both implement `TestRule` for some reason) ([Testcontainers’ issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/970) in case you are interested)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no scope that does exactly what you want here; `test` is the best available option.

A `test-runtime` scope has been requested before ([Re: Need for a test-runtime scope?](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200811.mbox/%3C17608340.3674701226307519843.JavaMail.adm-moff@moffice8.nsc.no%3E)) and the suggested workaround is exactly the `ignoreNonCompile` configuration you've already discovered.

`dependency:analyze` already has some limitations (["some cases are not detected (constants, annotations with source-only retention, links in javadoc)"](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/)). You may have to accept that any `test`-scope dependencies that it warns against are false positives.

(You *could* split the definition of your tests into a separate module, which would have no `slf4j` implementation dependencies, then run them in another module. I don't think that would be worth it.)

Comment: For the javadoc issue I have resorted to linking to the fully qualified class name and adding the base link url to the javadoc plugin and not declaring a dependency on the project. This avoids having an import statement and other potential negative issues of having a dependency listed which is not actually required.

Comment: Issue introduced [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6545).

Answer (score 5):

There is no concept of test-runtime in maven. The only real downside is the dependency analysis identifying these runtime test dependencies as unused. Since they are only test dependencies, however, this is pretty benign and cannot cause issues to other projects transitively dependent on this project.

Answer (score 4):

Since maven-dependency-plugin 2.10 ([revision 1649454](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1649454), Jan 2015), you can also add to the configuration a list of [ignoredDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#ignoredDependencies), [ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies) and [ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: These options were added just after I asked the question, and I think they they, in conjunction with the accepted answer, are the best approach available for dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i would suggest to have separate maven project with test cases that depend on main project

Answer (score 0):

See below.
Sources:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```